# Pairs of integer series with fixed asymptotic ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

Consider the two integer series $a(n)=n*2^n,b(n)=2^n$. Clearly $a=\Theta(b \log b)$. Another example with the same ratio would be $a(n)=n!\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1/i},b(n)=n!$. Which is even worse in sheer size of the numbers ($n!$ might be replaced with $LCM({1,\dots,n})$ but that doesn't exactly help). Of course $a(n)=\lfloor{n\log n}\rfloor,b(n)=n$ would be a minimum size solution, but it kinda cheats in two ways (the second being the repeating numbers).
Do you have an idea for $a=\Theta(b\log b)$ with no rounding and smallish numbers? ($a=\Theta(b\log\log b)$ would be even more interesting.)

Comment: How about $a=p_n$, $b=n$, $p_n$ being the $n$th prime?

Comment: So, how about it?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. There are so many other attention stealers at the moment :-) Yes, that is a valid solution. Still, I'd prefer something with a closed formula.

Comment: So you wouldn't be happy with $a_n=\sum^nd(m)$, $b_n=n$, where $d(m)$ is the number of divisors of $m$.

Comment: That actually counts :-) Maybe I should have added some background info: take a highly "chaotic" sequence like Calkin-Wilf of size n: *any* search of it (be it "static", or with a algorithm like Move-To-Root) on a binary search tree (here: Stern-Brocot) will take $n\log n$ time. So any sequence generated this way (e.g. static: just add all path lengths in the Stern-Brocot tree) might count, but it's a numerological nightmare. Maybe one of that sequences coincides with your suggestion.

Comment: The average case and the worst case of the best algorithms for sorting a list of $n$ items take $Cn\log n$ comparisons for some constant $C$. The worst case will give integers. See, for example, Merge sort, and Heapsort.

Comment: For merge sort, worst case number of comparisons is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A003071 and I believe the asymptotic is $n\log_2n$.

Comment: Are you psychic or what? (Or am I psychic? :-) Just two minutes after your post, and without reading it first, I tripped over A003071 in OEIS, which is exactly what you describe and (with a bit of tweaking - add a "master root", which adds $2^n$ for a tree of height $n$) is the sequence for the case I described. as "static". I generate the sequence this way: Take a complete balanced tree of height $n$. Add all node heights. S: Strike out the largest element, hang the dangling tree to its parent, add all node heights. Repeat S until the tree is empty. This too generates A003071.